# Connection timeout error for winscp to cloudera vm

Tags: windows, cloudera, file-transfer, winscp

I am trying to connect Cloudera VM from my Windows desktop using Winscp for file transfer.
But I am not able to connect it using winscp. It is showing me connection timeout error.
Anybody has any idea how to solve this issue.

Thanks,
Atul

Comment: Not a programming question.

Comment: Yes Martin, Its not a programming question but the issue I have faced while I want to transfer files to Hadoop system which is present on my VM.

Comment: But that's still does not make the question on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out, bow to do it. The error was I am referring wrong IP address. To know right IP address and connect follow below steps.
First, if the Cloudera VM is running then shutdown it.
Second, go to setting. refer below screenshots
[image: Click on settings]

[image: Click on Network]

[image: Click on Adapter2 and then set Attached to and Name as per screen shot]

Then start the Cloudera VM again.
Go to terminal.
Type the command ifconfig.
On Consol you will find eth1 - where you have to look for ipnet, next to it is your IP address, which you have to use to connect to VM. note down the address.
Go to windows.
Open Winscp.
Create New Site.
Put the host name as the IP address which we got from consol
Username- cloudera, password- cloudera
Port-22
Click on Save.
Click on login.

Hope this will help.

Thanks,
Atul

Answer (score 1):

I can connect to cloudera VM 5.15 from winSCP from my laptop(windows).

I am using Virtual box.

I have downloaded VM from cloudera official site and then choose option file-import appliance ,it will choose by default Network adapter NAT and then I followed as mentioned below.

add cloudera.quickstart in hosts file
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

## localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost       quickstart.cloudera
```

Recommended VirtualBox Configurations
Right click on the VirtualMachine and click Settings
Setup the VM to allow you to copy and paste from that machine to your local and vice-teversa
Click on General -> Advanced
Set Shared Clipboard to Bidirectional
Setup port forwarding from port 2222 to port 22 to allow SSH to the machine
Click on Network -> Advanced -> Port Forwarding
Add a new entry
Name: 2222
Host Port: 2222
Guest Port: 22
Accessing the VM
SSH’ing to the Machine
Default SSH Credentials: cloudera/cloudera

Host to connect to: localhost

Because of the Recommended VirtualBox Configuration above, we’re forwarding connections from port 2222 to 22. So you would want to use port 2222 to connect.

Windows
Open putty/winscp
Use ip as 127.0.0.1
Set 2222 as the port
Connection Type: SSH
Click open
Enter the password